# Is it safe to use username-password flow for Graph Api and Does this flow comes under Oauth implementation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to migrate from EWS to Microsoft graph api as Microsoft will no longer support basic authentication from October. While going through few online examples of Microsoft azure I came across below git location.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-desktop/tree/master/Username-Password-Flow

Is it okay if I migrate our web application to use the above method or am I using the wrong flow in our case
Does the Username-Password flow come under Microsoft Oauth

Answer (score 0):

We recommend that you move to an OAuth flow for your application and not bake user name and passwords in. Its unfortunate that the sample is called this because it is in fact using OAuth. The main user experience problem you will have otherwise is that any user with multi-factor auth on will not work.

We have some getting started tutorials for JAVA here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/java specific to Microsoft Graph that you can use to call Exchange APIs to replace your EWS API calls.

Comment: The thing is all the above implementation is kind of backend. We try to synchronize user's office 365 calendar events with our tool's Calendar.  There will be a place where he/she will enter the details of his/her account of office 365 and in the backend at midnight we try to connect to the Office 365 account's calendar and sync the data. What should we be doing in this case where user's login isn't really required?

Comment: For your scenario, you would require application permissions (app-only). This would require your Azure AD admins to admin consent this permission. That way you can iterate through all users calendars as your application without getting each user to consent it.

Comment: there is a great learning path to understand this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/m365-msgraph-associate/

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jeremy Thake MSFT. Is there any tutorial/working example on how Adminconsent works in java as an example.?

Comment: that tutorial on the get started page I showed will walk you through getting it going. Then you just need to pick a permission that requires admin consent like Group.ReadWrite.All to access a plan or message in a Team. When you are in delegated flow it'll prompt you and if they are an admin you can consent right there. or it'll request to the admin to approve the permission.